# genetic combination exercise

Tags: probability

Consider families with two children, in which both parents have been identified as carriers of an autosomal recessive allele (Aa). At least one of the children shows the corresponding phenotype. When adding all the children of such families, what proportion of them will show this phenotype?

Why is the correct answer 4/7? The answer was given by a genetic teacher where I'm studying

Comment: See updated answer for (aa) genotype. Teacher was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  A  a
A AA Aa
a Aa aa
```

Based on the Punnett square above there is a $1/4$ chance that a child will show the phenotype. Let $X$ be the number of children in the family of $2$ that show the phenotype. $X$ has pmf $\Pr(X=0)=9/16,\Pr(X=1)=6/16,\Pr(X=2)=1/16$. Then the conditional probability can be found $\Pr(X=0|X=1 or X=2)=0, \Pr(X=1|X=1 or X=2)=\frac{6/16}{6/16+1/16}=6/7,\Pr(X=2|X=1 or X=2)=\frac{1/16}{6/16+1/16}=1/7$. Then the expected value of $X/2$ given $X=1orX=2$ is $1/2\cdot \left(0+6/7\cdot 1+1/7\cdot 2\right)=4/7$.

So given that at least one child has the phenotype (aa), the expected proportion of children in the family of $2$ that shows the phenotype is $4/7$. Hey looks like the teacher was right after all.

Comment: it's necessary to have aa genotype to show that phenotype